# Most Efficient(in terms of speed of execution) way to map List<TypeA> to List<TypeB>

Tags: c#, .net, performance, execution-time

I have TypeA and B like this:

```
class TypeA
{

prop 1;
prop 2;
prop 3;
prop 4;
...
prop 15;
}

class TypeB
{

prop a;
prop b;
prop c;
...
prop p;
}
```

Each property value from TypeB will be constructed by manipulating some properties of TypeA.

Now I need to do something like

```
List<TypeB> list= SomeConverter(List<TypeA>);
```

Source list may contain around 5000 objects.

I would like to know the fastest way to do this. Code readability is not my concern.

There are few such types that I need to map.

Thanks

Comment: Not information to say, but you could look at storing the properties as a Dictionary<String,Dynamic> instead of discrete get/set for each one. Then converting is just mapping one dictionary key to another, or thereabouts anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You won't be able to avoid the cost of converting each instance of `TypeA` to an instance of `TypeB`, but you can avoid the cost of resizing the list by setting an initial capacity:

```
List<TypeB> listB = new List<TypeB>(listA.Count);
listB.AddRange(listA.Select(SomeConverter));

TypeB SomeConverter(TypeA input)
{
    return new TypeA() { ... };
}
```

Or this, for slightly better performance:

```
List<TypeB> listB = new List<TypeB>(listA.Count);
foreach(var a in listA)
{
    listB.Add(SomeConverter(a));
}
```

Of course, in many cases the biggest performance comes from over-zealously using lists in the first place. For example, calling `ToList()` when invoking a Linq query forces the query to be evaluated immediately, and the results saved into a `List<T>`. Instead, if you can defer evaluation until as late as possible, you'll usually avoid much of the most expensive processing. In general, unless you really need to do dynamic insert / deletes to the set, you almost certainly should avoid using lists.

Comment: +1 Although using LINQ will be *slightly* slower than writing a `for` loop.

Comment: I think old-fashion `for` loop would be quicker then `Select` method call (because of delegate usage).

Comment: @MarcinJuraszek / JimMischel, of course! Linq is just so natural for me these days, I didn't even consider using a plain old loop, but yeah, that should be slightly better.

Answer (score 1):

[AutoMapper](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper) is a decent library for such cases, didn't try it in huge lists, give it a try.